# vscode: symbol search, but only in my code

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

If I use ctrl-t (symbol search), I get all symbols. This means my symbols and symbols of libraries I use.

Is there a way to restrict symbol search to only the symbols which are in my code (excluding symbols from libraries).

I use vscode for Go.

[image: vscode-symbol-search-in-golang]

In above screenshot I highlighted the single line which comes from my code.

If a filter for "only my code" is not possible, then it would be nice if my code would get higlighted by vscode.

Related issue: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/37236

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Related issue: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/37236

That issue just got closed with [CL 490935](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/tools/+/490935) and commit [`golang/tools` commit 8e9b185](https://github.com/golang/tools/commit/8e9b1853d0adc8c8c3be333e518b6a44b4582945):

> ### gopls/internal/lsp/source: add the "symbolScope" option
>
> Add a new "`symbolScope`" option that controls whether matches are restricted to workspace packages only.
> <del>This is the new default behavior</del>, though the old behavior can be enabled by setting `"symbolScope": "all"`.

Actually, [CL 494217](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/tools/+/494217) keeps the default of this
setting at "`all`", and solicit feedback for which default our users
prefer.

You now have:

> ### `symbolScope` *enum*
>
> `symbolScope` controls which packages are searched for workspace/symbol
> requests.
>
> The default value, "`workspace`", searches only workspace
> packages.
> The legacy behavior, "`all`", causes all loaded packages to be
> searched, including dependencies; this is more expensive and may
> return unwanted results.
>
> Must be one of:
>
> - `"all"` matches symbols in any loaded package, including dependencies.
> - `"workspace"` matches symbols in workspace packages only.

This still might include [vendoring](https://go.dev/ref/mod#vendoring), which can be an issue.

---

Note: this does not include [#37237](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/37237) ("`x/tools/gopls`: support advanced query syntax for Symbol"):

> not until VS Code allows controlling the workspace symbol result dialog.
>
> As it is now, any sort of advanced query syntax would cause VS Code to filter out all results, because it does its own round of sorting and filtering after we return results.
>
> You can now test this out by building gopls@master:
>
> e.g.:
>
> ```bash
> git clone https://go.googlesource.com/tools
> cd tools/gopls && go install
> ```

---

[Thomas Güttler](https://github.com/guettli), the OP, [confirms](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/37236#issuecomment-1536778976):

> ctrl+t show now my code only:
>
> [image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/414336/236568501-aa61fcfe-1b28-43ae-a4cc-8f6b7af03f87.png]

---

There is a regression ([#60027](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/60027): `WorkspaceSymbol` returns strange results in strange order), which will be fixed with [gopls/v0.12.0](https://github.com/golang/go/milestone/282), thanks to [findleyr](https://github.com/findleyr).

And [Paul Jolly](https://github.com/myitcv) [adds](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/37236#issuecomment-1537907051):

> > this issue is about symbols outside the workspace. Did this change help you?
>
> not really. Because the scope in which I want to search for symbols changes.
>
> - Sometimes I want to search across the equivalent of the all package space,
> - sometimes just in the workspace,
> - sometimes just in the scope of the module to which the current file belongs,
> - sometimes the scope of the package to which the current file belongs,
> - sometimes in the scope of just the current file.
>
> Having a single static config option doesn't much help therefore.
> Not to say that it wouldn't help others, I'm just drawing a connection to a previously discussed issue.

Comment: It is not clear if it will be part of gopls 0.12.0, considering there already is a [0.12.0-pre1](https://github.com/golang/tools/releases/tag/gopls%2Fv0.12.0-pre.1) released last week.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [vscode-search-everywhere](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kbysiec.vscode-search-everywhere)

Refer

> Extension Settings

```
searchEverywhere.include: "**/*.{go,js,jsx,ts,tsx}"
```

*meaning: include all files with the above extentions*

Comment: Thank you very much. I use this and `!!foo` to search for all functions containing the word "foo" now.

Answer (score -1):

Enter the path of the libraries, in `files to exclude`.

Comment: I added a screenshot to the question. I don't see "files to exclude".

Comment: @guettli I believe they mean the Search feature that's in the activity bar (magnifying glass icon), which doesn't help you with your question.

Comment: @guettli
Here you can try this setting ids in vscode. 
go.gotoSymbol.includeGoroot and go.gotoSymbol.ignoreFolders

Comment: @Sahiljangra thank you for pointing me to the settings. But somehow this feels too complicated. Sometimes I want to search in all symbols, and sometimes I want to search only in my symbols. Updating the settings the settings for hitting ctrl-t feels slow.

Comment: @Sahiljangra [go.gotoSymbol.includeGoroot](https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/blob/master/docs/settings.md#gogotosymbolincludegoroot) "Not applicable when using the language server." AFAIK I use the language-server, and I think it makes no sense to turn it off. Or am I missing something.